# Showing points lie on the same circle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles

Let $\Delta ABC$ be a triangle and consider the line $t$ be tangent to the circumcircle of $\Delta ABC$ at the vertex $C$. The line $p$ parallel to the tangent $t$ intersects the lines
$AB$ and $AC$ at the points D and E, respectively.

Prove that the points $A, B, D, E$ belong to the same circle.

Comment: The tangent at C by definition intersects AC at C. How can it intersect AC again at E?

Comment: Shouldn't A, D, B be collinear?

Comment: The statement, as it's stated now must be wrong since $A,B,D$ are collinear.
I think the line $p$ parallel to $t$ intersects $AC$,$BC$ at $D,E$ respectively, in which case, think of the Broken Chord/Alternate Segment Theorem.

Answer (score 3):

- Because $FC||DE$ we have $\angle DEA = \angle FCA$
- Because of tangent-chord theorem we have $\angle ABC = \angle FCA$

Thus $\angle DEA = \angle ABC$ and so $A,B,D,E$ are concyclic.

[image]

Comment: Does this help you?